# Is it safe to use gdebi instead of Ubuntu Software Center to install .deb files?

Tags: package-management, deb, gdebi

I've noticed that Ubuntu 10.10 manages single .deb files with the Ubuntu Software Center. Since I find it too heavy to load I've installed **gdebi** with: `sudo apt-get install gdebi`
and I've set it as default application to open any .deb file.

My question is: is it safe/supported to use this kind of operation? I mean: does gdebi still relate to internal apt-get to satisfy dependencies and install .deb files?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be just fine to use gdebi the way you are using it.

Both accomplish the same thing.  Gdebi does relate to internal apt-get to satisfy dependencies and install .debs.  It worked in previous versions of Ubuntu, it will work in Maverick.

Answer (score 4):

Gdebi is still part of the standard Kubuntu installation and it still works the same there as it used to. As I understand it, the reason why it was removed in Ubuntu has nothing to do with problems with Gdebi, but rather with improvements to Software Center that made it extraneous.

I say, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

It is PERFECTLY safe.  I frequently prefer to use the lightweight GDebi instead of Software Center, especially during the SC installation bug period.

Comment: It's perfectly safe assuming the source .DEB is safe. :)

Comment: @Broam: Yes, but in that case using Software Center will not make it any better, unless the SC has some special way of protecting against unsafe debs.