# How to install .deb files the old fashion way?

Tags: installation, software-center, deb, gdebi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to use gdebi instead of Ubuntu Software Center to install .deb files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10865/is-it-safe-to-use-gdebi-instead-of-ubuntu-software-center-to-install-deb-files)

Is there a way to install DEB-files the old fashion way in Ubuntu 11.10? I can't install them through Software Central (Programcentral För Ubuntu in Swedish). I wanna be abel to install them like in 7.10. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/10865/18612

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Ubuntu 7.10 used GDebi for installing `.deb` files.
Just install GDebi (GTK) from the software centre and set it as the default application for handling `.deb` files.

Answer (score 4):

Why can you not install them via the software center ?

What do you mean "like in 7.10" ?

```
sudo apt-get install foo
```

apt-get will resolve dependencies.

```
sudo dpkg -i your_package.deb
```

with dpkg you will need to resolve dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You can open a terminal and type:

`sudo dpkg -i ~/path.to.deb`