# Draftsight for ubuntu 32bit

Tags: software-installation, cad

Again surprised by DraftSight. Since DraftSight 2015 it is unsupported on Linux 32bit machines. As always, previous beta version stops working.

Does anybody know if there is a way to either install ds2015 on 32bit ubuntu or get somewhere and cause to work a previous ds version?

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: The same problem is being asked about in the other question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/540608/draftsight-ubuntu-14-04