# How do I run Pinguy Builder 4.X on Xubuntu 16.04/xfce from terminal?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, lxterminal

I have previously installed Pinguy Builder beta; however, after looking in the Wisker Menu I couldn't find Pinguy Builder. Then I tried in terminal:

`gksu pinguybuilder`

However nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the README found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/)

```
Q: How do I run this in the terminal without using the GUI?
A: sudo PinguyBuilder
```

Example: `sudo PinguyBuilder dist`

Related Note:
It's been [reported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890248/how-do-i-run-pinguy-builder-4-x-on-xubuntu-16-04-xfce-from-terminal/890252?noredirect=1#comment1392536_890252) that you can launch this using the GUI
with the command `PinguyBuilder-gtk`
 **(Command string is case sensitive. Must use capital 'P' & 'B')**

Comment: Do you know how to boot in GUI????

Comment: I just looked at your source! And have seen it uses case sensitive! Maybe gksu PinguyBuilder will work?

Comment: Weird? You would expect dpkg -i and apt -f would do the same?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/813455/225694

Comment: OK =-O! Will try tomorrow on my VM!

Comment: Will tick if it works

Comment: I just tried and it comes up :) However when i try sudo PinguyBuilder-gtk it doesn't work. But It works with just PinguyBuilder-gtk