# Slow (Wireless) Internet Connection on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, internet, connection

I have recently erased my hard drive and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it (Before I had dual booted windows 8.1 pro with ubuntu 18.04) . My problem is that now I have a REALLY slow connection (aprox 200-300 kbps) which is not what i experienced on WS (10 mbps +). How do I fix this? Here's some info : 
https://pastebin.com/T3reYKLM
Thanks!

Comment: Though the difference you reporting looks suspicious *(I mean, like a bug, or whatever)*, however offhand to improve wireless speed I can suggest [upgrading linux kernel to 4.17](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade). AFAIK at that point all discussed at [this article and its comments](https://lwn.net/Articles/757643/) patches should've landed.

Comment: I tried to update the kernel and it seems that something isn't right... Here's a log: https://pastebin.com/RcefxLC5

Comment: You downloaded "lowlatency" and "generic" and "unsigned" kernels. They're mutually exclusive, please, use only packages that have "generic" in their name *(there would be just 3 of them: modules, headers, and image)*. Also, use latest release of 4.17, which is, ATM, [`4.17.19`](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17.19/).

Comment: Same errors.... This time only  linux-headers-4.17.19-041719-generic failed to install. https://pastebin.com/tCLs0zq9

Comment: Oh, it depends on libssl1.1, which does not exist for 16.04 *(16.04 have many outdated packages, allegedly because they stable, it's a typical practice on Ubuntu)*. It [does however exist for 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libssl1.1). I can't say offhand whether it's okay to install, but you can try. Ubuntu usually pretty good in dealing with dependencies, so likely it would be okay, but don't take my word for it. And side note: please, [use gdebi instead of dpkg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621351/gdebi-vs-dpkg-how-does-gdebi-automatically-gets-missing-dependancies-can-i-u).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.
I've tried almost everything : propritary driver,open source driver, blacklist driver, update kernel, etc ...

nothing worked !

Upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 fix the problem

Comment: I really don't want to (18.04 is really laggy for me + last time i had 16.04 everything was fine ) ...