# Kernel Update (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: drivers, kernel

Hello I have to update my NVIDIA driver, but I think I have to put last kernel (5.11).  I made all update system via the GUI, but my kernel remains the 5.8

- Why the software update doesn't make it?
- Is it ok to install it myself via the terminal?

THanks

edit :
[image]
[image]

Comment: What NVIDIA card do you have?

Comment: geforce rtx 3070

Comment: The 460 driver that is in the Ubuntu repositories should be able to support that card without going to an Unsupported kernel version.

Comment: i have the 460.39 installed. It seems i need to upgrade for davinci, right now it doesn't work, i have also lot of issue in blender.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the drivers should always match the version of the kernel.
If you, for any reason, need v5.11 of the driver, you should install v5.11 of the kernel.

In addition, the numbers you are quoting look very strange.
Please *post the output of*

```
$ uname -a
$ dpkg -l | grep ii | grep \ linux-
$ dpkg -l | grep rc | grep \ linux-
```

and the [list of repos you have](https://askubuntu.com/a/148954/226614)

```
$ grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

---

-**Why the software update doesn't make it?**

Perhaps you didn't do

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Please *post the exact command you used* when trying the update.

-**Is it ok to install it myself via the terminal?**

What do you mean by this?

Using `apt` (this is ok), or installing from `.deb` (not recommended, but [if you *need* it](https://sypalo.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu)...)?

I never tried it with the type of installation you mean to do, but if you want to install from `.deb` I guess [`gdebi` is also preferred instead of `dpkg`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621351/gdebi-vs-dpkg-how-does-gdebi-automatically-gets-missing-dependancies-can-i-u).

Comment: ok thanks but why the system update doesn't install the last one?

Comment: @SHURA - Please see updated answer and post your output.
Most likely they are not yet in the repos you have configured. Let me check and post back.

Comment: sorry i misspelled, i have kernel 5.8.0-4 . I have updated the system via the software not terminal. So my wondering is : if the update software doesnt install the last kernel, is it for a reason or it's a bug? I just want to be sure before updating via the terminal..

Comment: @SHURA - Please post exactly what is asked... an explanation without verbatim information may be misleading.

Comment: i edited my question, your grep rc command returns nothing.

Comment: @SHURA - It is best if you copy and paste the text instead of a screen capture, so others can also copy-paste.
Plus, please post the exact command you used when trying the update.

Comment: i think you just don't wanna help and pushing until i explode no?

Comment: @SHURA - Certainly not. 
Pasting a screen capture is easier for you, but it does not make it "easy" for others.
Given that you are asking for help, and others like me are devoting some time for free to help you, I guess it's best if you help others help you.
If you consider a request for executing some commands that provide useful information, or a request for a copy-paste of text, too heavy/close to an explosion, I sincerely regret that. 
Good luck.